# Longtable spread too wide

Tags: tables

I've created some tabular output through Python (pandas database). However, it leaves a too wide space between columns 2,3 (for which I cannot detect the reason), and actually overflowing the page width.

Sample code is below

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{letterpaper}                   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{lrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
\toprule
{} &     $\underline Y$ &   $\bar Y $ &  $\epsilon$ &   $\bar p$ &    $\underline s$ &  $\bar s$ &   $\theta$ &  $\underline\theta$ &  $\bar\theta$ &      u &     $\underline v$ &   $\bar v$ &     $\underline w$ &   $\bar w$ \\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\
\midrule
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
0 &  0.532 &  0.394 &      1.0 &  1.349 &  0.20 &  0.40 &  32.223 &  12.978 &    19.245 &  0.074 &  0.960 &  1.424 &  0.423 &  0.458 \\
1 &  0.603 &  0.317 &      1.0 &  1.901 &  0.15 &  0.65 &  38.459 &  11.728 &    26.731 &  0.079 &  0.928 &  2.115 &  0.485 &  0.576 \\
2 &  0.566 &  0.361 &      0.5 &  1.253 &  0.20 &  0.40 &  30.642 &  13.475 &    17.167 &  0.073 &  0.986 &  1.256 &  0.407 &  0.433 \\
3 &  0.504 &  0.422 &      2.0 &  1.428 &  0.20 &  0.40 &  33.573 &  12.558 &    21.015 &  0.075 &  0.937 &  1.568 &  0.437 &  0.479 \\
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

[image: table screenshot]

Comment: the space is created by `\multicolumn{3}{r}{{Continued on next page}}`, if it helps...

Comment: but still, the table is too large (with the present margins).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your table has fifteen [15!] columns, reducing the value of `\tabcolsep` -- the parameter that governs the amount of intercolumn whitespace -- is helpful.

In the following example, the thin line above the table is inserted just to illustrate the width of the text block.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{letterpaper,margin=1in} 
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable}
\begin{document}

{\setlength\tabcolsep{3.5pt} % default value: 6pt
\begin{longtable}{@{} l *{14}{r} @{}}
\toprule
& $\underline Y$ & $\bar Y $ & $\epsilon$ & $\bar p$ & $\underline s$ & $\bar s$ & $\theta$ & $\underline\theta$ & $\bar\theta$ & u & $\underline v$ & $\bar v$ & $\underline w$ & $\bar w$ \\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{15}{r}{Continued on next page} \\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
0 & 0.532 & 0.394 & 1.0 & 1.349 & 0.20 & 0.40 & 32.223 & 12.978 & 19.245 & 0.074 & 0.960 & 1.424 & 0.423 & 0.458 \\
1 & 0.603 & 0.317 & 1.0 & 1.901 & 0.15 & 0.65 & 38.459 & 11.728 & 26.731 & 0.079 & 0.928 & 2.115 & 0.485 & 0.576 \\
2 & 0.566 & 0.361 & 0.5 & 1.253 & 0.20 & 0.40 & 30.642 & 13.475 & 17.167 & 0.073 & 0.986 & 1.256 & 0.407 & 0.433 \\
3 & 0.504 & 0.422 & 2.0 & 1.428 & 0.20 & 0.40 & 33.573 & 12.558 & 21.015 & 0.075 & 0.937 & 1.568 & 0.437 & 0.479 \\
\end{longtable}
} % end of scope of "\setlength\tabcolsep{3.5pt} "
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all to suppress the white, since the `Continued on next page` text is right-aligned, you must use `\multicolumn{total number of columns}`.

This being settled you can either use the `landscape` environment and keep defaul spacing parameters, or reduce `tabcolsep` and/or `font size`. Here is a code that shows both results.

I also replaced the `\bar` accent (too small for capital letters) with `\widebar`, borrowed from the `mathabx` fonts (package not loaded, as it interferes with default maths fonts).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry} % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{letterpaper, showframe, nomarginpar} % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ...%
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
<-6> mathx5 <6-7> mathx6 <7-8> mathx7
<8-9> mathx8 <9-10> mathx9
<10-12> mathx10 <12-> mathx12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathAccent{\widebar}{0}{mathx}{"73}

\begin{document}

{\setlength\tabcolsep{3.7pt}\small
\begin{longtable}{l*{14}{r}}
\toprule
{} & $ \underline {Y\!}$ & $ \widebar Y $ & $\epsilon$ & $\widebar p$ & $\underline s$ & $\widebar s$ & $ θ $ & $\underline θ $ & $\widebar\theta$ & u & $\underline v$ & $\widebar v$ & $\underline w$ & $\widebar w$ \\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{15}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\
\midrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
0 & 0.532 & 0.394 & 1.0 & 1.349 & 0.20 & 0.40 & 32.223 & 12.978 & 19.245 & 0.074 & 0.960 & 1.424 & 0.423 & 0.458 \\
1 & 0.603 & 0.317 & 1.0 & 1.901 & 0.15 & 0.65 & 38.459 & 11.728 & 26.731 & 0.079 & 0.928 & 2.115 & 0.485 & 0.576 \\
2 & 0.566 & 0.361 & 0.5 & 1.253 & 0.20 & 0.40 & 30.642 & 13.475 & 17.167 & 0.073 & 0.986 & 1.256 & 0.407 & 0.433 \\
3 & 0.504 & 0.422 & 2.0 & 1.428 & 0.20 & 0.40 & 33.573 & 12.558 & 21.015 & 0.075 & 0.937 & 1.568 & 0.437 & 0.479 \\
\end{longtable}
}
\clearpage
\newgeometry{showframe = false}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{l*{14}{r}}
\toprule
{} & $ \underline {Y\!}$ & $ \widebar Y $ & $\epsilon$ & $\widebar p$ & $\underline s$ & $\widebar s$ & $ θ $ & $\underline θ $ & $\widebar\theta$ & u & $\underline v$ & $\widebar v$ & $\underline w$ & $\widebar w$ \\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{15}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\
\midrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
0 & 0.532 & 0.394 & 1.0 & 1.349 & 0.20 & 0.40 & 32.223 & 12.978 & 19.245 & 0.074 & 0.960 & 1.424 & 0.423 & 0.458 \\
1 & 0.603 & 0.317 & 1.0 & 1.901 & 0.15 & 0.65 & 38.459 & 11.728 & 26.731 & 0.079 & 0.928 & 2.115 & 0.485 & 0.576 \\
2 & 0.566 & 0.361 & 0.5 & 1.253 & 0.20 & 0.40 & 30.642 & 13.475 & 17.167 & 0.073 & 0.986 & 1.256 & 0.407 & 0.433 \\
3 & 0.504 & 0.422 & 2.0 & 1.428 & 0.20 & 0.40 & 33.573 & 12.558 & 21.015 & 0.075 & 0.937 & 1.568 & 0.437 & 0.479 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]